# Hiding a parent div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide

i have a problem with jQuery. I have this:

[image]

And i want that when you click on the black part of the page, the black part and the image dissapear. Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div id="fade-wrapper">
    <div class="row-1-big"><img src="css/images/galeria/1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="row-2-big"><img src="css/images/galeria/2.jpg"></div>
    <div class="row-3-big"><img src="css/images/galeria/3.jpg"></div>
    <div class="row-4-big"><img src="css/images/galeria/4.jpg"></div>
    <div class="row-5-big"><img src="css/images/galeria/5.jpg"></div>
    <div class="row-6-big"><img src="css/images/galeria/6.jpg"></div>
    <div class="row-7-big"><img src="css/images/galeria/7.jpg"></div>
    <div class="row-8-big"><img src="css/images/galeria/8.jpg"></div>
    <div class="row-9-big"><img src="css/images/galeria/9.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var r1 = $('.row-1'); //this is for when you click the thumbnail

r1.click(function(){
   $('#fade-wrapper').show(300);
   $('.row-1-big').delay(400).show();
});
```

the problem is that if I add this code:

```
$('#fade-wrapper').click(function(){
   $('this').hide();
});
```

when i click the image (row-1-big) it hides all and I wan't that the content hide just when I click the black part. If you don't understand just tell me.

Comment: does $('this') need to be $(this)? not sure that would cause your problem though

Comment: yeah sorry, typing error but not the problem

Comment: when you say you want the content to be hidden, what specifically is the "content"?

Comment: image and black background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to click outside the Div wrapper which is the black area then close the whole thing, here is how:

```
//Click on html 
$('html').click(function(){
  //hide
  $('#fade-wrapper').hide();
});

// prevent the fadeIn area to hide when clicked
$('#fade-wrapper').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Comment: I added the `$('#fade-wrapper').hide();` line before you edit the answer, but it didn't work either :/

Comment: $('html') instead of $(html)

Comment: what happened when you clicked?

Comment: if you are using fade-wrapper as the background, all you need is to change $('html') to $('#fade-wrapper') and $('#fade-wrapper') to $('#fade-wrapper div')

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **[e.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)** here to prevent click event fire on the parent div when you click on the child images:

```
$('#fade-wrapper').click(function(){
   $(this).hide();
});

$('#fade-wrapper img').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Also note that you don't need to wrap `this` inside quotes since `this` is an object not a string.

Comment: typing error, and yes, it should work but it doesn't, i've tried yet

Comment: Did you use `e.stopPropagation()` which I've suggested?

Comment: yes, but when i click he black background nothing happens, not either when i click the image

Comment: What is the black background HTML. Can you post all the relevant HTML markup?

Answer (score 1):

To get the parent you would do -

```
$('#fade-wrapper').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().hide(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you check the div which is actually clicked with something like this :

```
$('#fade-wrapper').click(function(e){
    if (e.target.id === 'fade-wrapper')
        $(this).hide();
});
```